# GUI for video files in the Windows Phone Isolated Storage

Tags: c#, windows, windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8-sdk

I'm currently working on a Windows Phone (8.0) application that can record video's. I want to save multiple video files in the Isolated Storage, but i can't find a way to view these saved files in a nice graphical interface with thumnails and information about length or size (much like the Windows Phone Camera Roll).

Could someone help me with this? There doesnt seem to be a lot of documentation on viewing the video files from the isolated storage.

Maybe it's something stupid, but i'm relatively new to developping for phones.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: And what about creating your own gallery viewer?

Comment: Thats what i'm trying to figure out to do, but i've got no idea how to get thumbnails and fileinfo.

Answer (score 0):

1) I am not clear about your requirement but if you want see the Isolated Storage files in your machine you can use "Windows Phone Power Tools". For more info visit : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh286408(v=vs.105).aspx

2) If you planning to make your own video gallary in Windows Phone app

Use AudioVideoCaptureDevice class to record videos and implement "PreviewFrameAvailable" event of it.

In that event, implement videoCaptureDevice.GetPreviewBufferArgb(argbPx)  method.

For the size of video, when your read file from IsolatedStorage, you will get bytes array for data. That is the size of file. Covert it to Mb, Kb, etc format you want.